# Powershell-command Invoke-webrequest login form hangs

Tags: powershell, curl, uri

Using Powershell 5.0.10586.117 I want to request a specific web-site (on IIS 8.5) containing a form to log-in. Here is the specific code:

```
$Url = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri "https://not-work/hello.aspx" -SessionVariable SesVar
$UrlForm = $Url.Forms[0]
```

When doing so Powershell hangs and never returns anything as long as I do not interrupt manually.

Using

```
$Url = Invoke-Webrequest -Verbose -Uri "https://not-work/hello.aspx" -SessionVariable SesVar
```

I can see the following error:

> VERBOSE: Get https://not-work/hello.aspx with 0-byte payload.

Running the same website in Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 it works. Using an older version of the application code on a different (likely older IIS) it works too in Powershell.

So I am wondering, if this issue has to do with this [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1557783/invoke-webrequest-hangs-in-some-cases-unless-usebasicparsing-is-used) in Powershell?

Note: Even when using

```
$Url = Invoke-Webrequest -UseBasicParsing -Verbose -Uri "https://not-work/hello.aspx" -SessionVariable SesVar
```

it fails.

For the sake of completeness, *curl* also gives an HTTP status code 200 (like in Chrome), but there are some differences in comparison to the working version:

**Non-working website**

```
C:\Tools\curl>curl -k https://not-work/hello.aspx -I HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Length: 12671 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: __AntiXsrfToken=d438e79fe7004ad09d950a3b8b4e507d; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 13:57:33 GMT
```

**Working website**

```
C:\Tools\curl>curl -k https://works-well/hello.aspx -I HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private  Content-Length: 12306 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
Server: WWW Server/1.1 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
Set-Cookie: __AntiXsrfToken=6142de1c5d474da780530da39fea033f; path=/;HttpOnly; Secure
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:56:47 GMT
```

By the way, in Internet Explorer (IE) 11.0.9600.18537 objects like images are not loaded (as I believe Powershell works "under the hood" using IE DLLs) and the "hourglass" is running permanently too next to the tab of the requested URI.

So again my question: Has this issue to do with this [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1557783/invoke-webrequest-hangs-in-some-cases-unless-usebasicparsing-is-used) in Powershell or could it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm troubleshooting my own situation of the same nature. My website seems to have changed a few things around. One of which is the FORMS.

Can you confirm that your website has a FORMS option?

EX.

```
#GET WEBSESSION
$url = "https://myaccount.nytimes.com/"
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable ws -UseBasicParsing
return $r
```

Notice that I use -UseBasicParsing. For my nytimes example I have to. This is because nytimes is using JS and that doesn't seem to return well for PS. Removing -UseBasicParsing will result in my WebRequest hanging.

You will notice that with the above return the 'FORMS : ' is null.

Right now I do not have a solution. Other than, my website clearly requires credentials and I clearly need to provide. So I'm now writing a muttery of different attempts using -Body $bodyParam @{} and -Headers $headerParams @{}. So far it's to no avail.

Simply put, PS doesn't seem to behave well with JS type websites and FORMS seems to be used for only a specific set of website, not for all  type sites.

Hopefully someone more skilled can assist cause this is racking my brain.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that "my" website has a FORMS-option.